# How to calculate the interest amount per day

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I need to implement this calculation in my project...

Its a simple calculation But I dont know... I googled about that but can't to find the solution....

I have the following values (*note:its a dynamic value*)

```
Interest rate (per day) => 0.17%
Amount => 1500
Days => 15
```

How can I calculate the interest amount ????

Please helpme :(

Comment: Do you want the interest compounded daily?

Comment: s may be!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the amount is compounded every day then the total with interest after 15 days worth of interest is $$1500\times\underset{\text{15 times}}{\underbrace{1.0017\times1.0017\times\dots\times1.0017}}=1500\times1.0017^{15}
 $$

(hopefully if that's not quite right you can change it so that it's the right number, i.e. compounded the right number of times)

Comment: A couple of zeros are missing. Also, the result is the total money after 15 days.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz whoaaa thanks

Comment: hw to calc 1.0017 from 0.17 ??? If u dont mind please tell me the logic